# How do I modify the url that generate by submit

Tags: python, django

I am using python 3.6 and django 3.0X

The problem I have is:

I want the flow is that when user select a brand and submit. The url path will generate as http://127.0.0.1:8000/show/car:Ford and link to url.py to pass to show.html

However when submit, the url path generated as http://127.0.0.1:8000/show?car=Ford

How can I get the correct url path that meet url.py.
That is why there are a '?' and '=' in url path?

Or how do I modify the url.py to meet the url path that generated by search.html?

Below are my codes:

search.html

```
<form name='my form' action='/show' method='GET'>
<label for='brand'> Select a brand </label>
<select name='car'>
    {% for m in maker %}
        <option value= '{{ m }}'> {{ m }} </option>
    {% endfor %}
</select><br> 
<input type='submit' value='Go' />
```

show.html

```
Model:<br>
{% for m in model %}
{{ m }}
{% endfor %}
<br>
```

url.py

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('', views.index),
path('index/', views.index),
path('welcome/', views.welcome),
path('django_plotly_dash/', include('django_plotly_dash.urls')),
path('search/', views.search),
path('index/buttons.html', views.buttons),
path('show/car:<str:brand>', views.show, name='show-url')
```

]

Views.py

```
def search(request):
    car = models.Cars.objects.all()
    df_car = read_frame(car)
    maker = list(df_car['make'].str.capitalize().unique())
    #maker = models.Cars.objects.values('make').distinct()
    return render(request, 'search.html', locals())


def show(request, brand):
    car = models.Cars.objects.filter(make=brand)
    df_car = read_frame(car)
    model = df_car.model.unique()

    return render(request, 'show.html', locals())
```

Comment: instead of images post your code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @zero Thanks! I modified it.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot change the way how URLs work. The question mark separates the regular URL and the query -- which is the additional information being passed to the URL. If you forced changing it, the URL won't load properly and plus, there's not really any point in doing so.

If you're wondering if something like `path('whatever/<str:name>, ...)` will work in the format with question marks, it will.

Comment: I see. Then there must be some area I did not doing properly. Thanks a lot!!